# change the order of a common legend, in a superimposed graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to change the order of my legend, and not to display them in alphabetical order as you can see below. I would like to have

```
"NONE","LIGHT","MEDIUM","HEAVY","V_COLD","COLD","MEDIUM","HOT".
```

Is it possible? I tried with several arguments but without success.

Below, my table :

```
structure(list(SOUNAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "BALLYSHANNON (CATHLEENS FALL)", class = "factor"), 
    year_month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("2013-03", 
    "2013-04", "2013-05", "2013-06", "2013-07", "2013-08", "2013-09", 
    "2013-10", "2013-12"), class = "factor"), pre_type = structure(c(4L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("HEAVY", "LIGHT", "MEDIUM", 
    "NONE"), class = "factor"), pre_value = c(13L, 2L, 11L, 5L, 
    9L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 15L, 4L, 16L, 
    2L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 
    14L, 1L, 5L, 19L, 6L), tem_type = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("COLD", "HOT", "MEDIUM", "V_COLD"
    ), class = "factor"), tem_value = c(0L, 7L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 
    29L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 29L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 25L, 
    0L, 0L, 18L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 
    24L, 0L, 7L), cnt_vehicle = c(NA, 2754406, NA, NA, NA, 2846039, 
    NA, NA, NA, 3149377, NA, NA, NA, 3058810, NA, NA, NA, 3362614, 
    NA, NA, NA, 3415716, NA, NA, NA, 3020812, NA, NA, NA, 3076665, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2775306, NA, NA), x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L
    )), .Names = c("SOUNAME", "year_month", "pre_type", "pre_value", 
"tem_type", "tem_value", "cnt_vehicle", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below my graph:

```
   ggplot(data = b_complet_2013, aes(x = x, y = pre_value*100000, fill = pre_type), stat = "identity") + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=(1:9)+0.2, labels=unique(b_complet_2013$year_month)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.3) +
      xlab("date") + ylab ("Number of days of précipitations(left) and temperatures (ritght)") +
      ggtitle("Precipitation per month") +
      geom_bar(data=b_complet_2013,aes(x=x+0.4, y=tem_value*100000, fill=tem_type), width=0.3, stat = "identity") +
      xlab("date") + ylab("Number of days of precipitations(left) and temperatures (ritght)") +
      ggtitle("Impact of weather on road traffics")  + theme( axis.title.y = element_text(color = "blue", face = "bold")) + 
      theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = "blue", face = "bold", size=9)) + theme( axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold")) + 
      theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "black", size = 9, face = "bold"))  +
      geom_line(mapping = aes(x= x+0.2, y = as.numeric(cnt_vehicle)), colour = I("blue"), size = 0.8) + 
      geom_point(aes(x= x+0.2, y = as.numeric(cnt_vehicle), colour = I("blue")), show.legend=FALSE, stat = "identity") +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100000,name="Number of days of precipitations(left) and temperatures (ritght)")) + 
      theme( plot.title = element_text(size = 17)) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12)) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
      labs(y = "Number of vehicles", color ="black") + 
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(linetype = "dashed", fill="white"), plot.background = element_rect(linetype = "dashed",fill="grey90" ))
```

Comment: Is all that ggplot code really necessary for your question? Try to give a _minimal_ example, this will make it much more clear for everyone, including future users with the same problem

Comment: Thanks but I have already try that and without success

Comment: Then please reduce your problem to the minimal code for which the issue still occurs. Remove all fluff. This way you are much more likely to receive an answer. One option: `scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("NONE","LIGHT","MEDIUM","HEAVY","V_COLD","COLD","MEDIUM","HOT"))`. Use limits instead of breaks to also change the order of the colors, not just the legend.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I have two times "MEDIUM", is it possible to put it in a different color (one for precipitations and another for temperatures,because it's not the same)?

Comment: You can't directly. But, you can rename one of them, and then use the `labels` argument to give the correct labels.

Comment: Yes, great idea, thank you.